# How to Scrape CSS icon with python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping payment methods of [website](https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=dell) but all payment methods are added with the help of CSS. I don't know how to scrape that code. I tried to find on StackOverflow but unable to find any helpful material. 
payment methods are given at the end of the page on the bottom left side.

```
payment_method = soup.find("div", class_="footer-second")
payyment_method = payment_method.find("div", class_="drz-footer-width-25 payment-column")
payment_method = payment_method.find_all("span")
```

this is the code that I used. But I don't have an idea of how I can scrape class images or image links I am unable to code further. There is no href or src link in tag only CSS class is used to show the icon on the page.

Comment: What have you tried? post your code

Comment: I tried simple code. I have no idea how to scrape these CSS images. 
payment_method = soup.find("div", class_="footer-second")
payment_method = payment_method.find("div", class_="drz-footer-width-25 payment-column")
payment_method = payment_method.find_all("span")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from an image url. You would need to regex out the image url from the relevant source css file and then try some form of optical recognition software. The following gets you the url.

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://laz-g-cdn.alicdn.com/lzdmod/desktop-footer-daraz/5.2.38/??pc/index.css')
p = re.compile(r'icon-yatra-v-pk{.*\.drz-footer-sprit{background-image:url\((.*?)\);')
image_url = 'https:' + p.findall(r.text)[0]
print(image_url)
```

Regex:

[image]

The css instructions place parts of this image "in frame" via the class attributes and css styling instructions. For example, enter `.icon-yatra-payment-8` in browser and hit enter then examine the css instructions for the node; you will see background-position, width and height specified as well as the background image as inline-block. You will also see links to the source css files for these instructions.

Comment: When I implement your code, A syntax error appear on p = re.compile(r'icon-yatra-v-pk{.*\.drz-footer-sprit{background-image:url\((.*?)\);').

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? I just ran it again without a problem. What you have pasted above is incorrect. You haven't escaped the ()

Comment: I copy compile code from your answer and paste it in this answer. Please share your p = re.compile code which you run.

Comment: `p = re.compile(r'icon-yatra-v-pk{.*\.drz-footer-sprit{background-image:url\((.*?)\);')`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Another question, I want to get only one or two images out of all these images like visa or Mastercard. How I can do it? The website is showing those images individually but we are getting all together.

Comment: The website is using css instructions to display parts of the overall image.

Comment: thanks for the help. This is not exactly what I was looking for. My exact requirement was payment method and I don't want to open more than one question for one requirement. My whole requirement was not satisfied but because I don't need that code anymore so I am considering this an answer.